# R simulate binomial multilevel data to estimate power for various ICCs

Tags: r, simulation, hierarchical-data, mixed-models, sample-size

In advance I'd like to apologize for the length of this post :S
[EDITS BELOW]

I would like to do a sample size calculation for a cluster randomized trial with a binary outcome.
Outcome is whether patients make use of a help service or not; Y= use help service (Y/N)
Patients are nested within clinics (five types) which are nested within hospitals.

We have an education program directed at hospital staff to promote the help service, and the main question to be answered by the trial is ‘Does the education program increase the proportion of patients making use the of the help line in the first 3 months after the completion of the education program?’. The education program will be rolled out in ‘experimental hospitals’; nothing will be done in control hospitals.

Not all patients will be using the service, as not all of them will have unmet needs after talking to their clinician/nurses. The level of unmet needs is believed to differ between clinics (clinics providing more severe treatments have higher unmet needs, and thus a larger group of ‘potential helpline users’).

Expected percentage of patients using the help service in control sites = 10%
Expected percentage of patients using the help service in experimental sites = 20%

Intraclass coefficient is unknown, but other studies have shown ICC of 0.09 and 0.15. I am interested in assessing sample size over the ICC range of 0 to 0.20.

For now, I assume that the education program can be rolled out instantaneously in all hospitals randomized to the experimental treatment and that patients only visit 1 clinic. The data available to assess the effectiveness of the program are;
•   Number of patients seen per clinic in the three month period
•   Number of patients using the help service in the three month period
We do not have individual patient data (as some might like to stay anonymous when using the help service), but aggregate data at the clinic level.

I have found the R package ‘CRTSize’, that can calculate the number of clusters needed for two level data (patients within hospital):

```
library(CRTSize)

pc.=0.10
pe.=0.20
ICCsteps <- c(0.0000001, 0.05,0.10, 0.15)
Msteps=c(25, 50,100,200,300)

results <- data.frame(pe=c(), pc=c(), m=c(), ICC=c(), Clusters_contr=c(),  Clusters_exp=c())

 for(i in seq_along(ICCsteps)){

for(m in seq_along(Msteps)){
print(paste("ICC=",ICCsteps[i], "m=", Msteps[m]))

mm <- n4props(pe=pe., pc=pc., m=Msteps[m], ICC=ICCsteps[i], alpha=0.05, power = 0.80, AR=1, two.tailed=TRUE, digits=3)

results_temp <- data.frame(pe=pe., pc=pc., m=mm$m, ICC=mm$ICC, Clusters_contr=ceiling(mm$nC), Clusters_exp=ceiling(mm$nE))
results <- rbind(results, results_temp)
  }
}

results
results$TotalClustersNeeded <- results$Clusters_contr +  results$Clusters_exp

par(mar=c(4,4,3,4))
plot(results$m, results$TotalClustersNeeded, type="n", xlab="Number of samples within cluster", ylab="Total number of clusters needed (half control/half intervention)", las=1);grid()
title(paste("Total # clusters needed to have 80% power with \n alfa 0.05 to show a difference between", pc.*100, "% vs. ", pe.*100, "%"))
for(i in seq_along(ICCsteps)){
points(results$m[results$ICC ==ICCsteps[i]], results$TotalClustersNeeded[results$ICC ==ICCsteps[i]], type="l")
text(max(Msteps)*0.90, min(results$TotalClustersNeeded[results$ICC ==ICCsteps[i]])+3, paste("ICC=", ICCsteps[i]), las=1)
}
```

So when I have around 200 pts per hospital, and ICC of 0.15, id need about 65 hospitals (half randomized to control, half randomized to intervention)

I don’t think it can model the three levels I will have in my data (pts/clinics/hospitals). Additional complications will be that hospitals will vary in the number of patients seen and that not all hospitals will have all types of clinics as some hospitals might be more specialized.

So I am trying to simulate some data. 
I don't know how to simulate data with specific ICCs, but I think I found a way around it (see below). 
Patients in each control-hospital have 10% probability to call the help line (20% in intervention hospitals). I have added a hospital specific error around these percentages. Each hospital has between 1-4 clinics. The proportion used to draw  x samples from the binomial distribution is the same between the clinics within a hospital (x is number of patients in a clinic).

I have tweaked the hospital error in a way that the ICC is around 0.15. However, the ICC varies for each simulation. I thought, that when I run many simulations I’d get enough simulations within say 0.145-0.155 to say something about power at ICC = 0.15.

This is what I have done so far:

```
 library(reshape2)
    library(lme4)
    library(plyr)
# Parameters
hospitals <- 30;h=1 # I set it up this way to be able to loop over several sample sizes, however, at the moment i am not using it. 

clinics <- data.frame(clinic =c("CT", "RT", "Surg", "Pal"),
                      prop.clin.hosp   = c(0.70, 0.80, 0.50  , 0.40),
                      Unmet.needs = c("45", "30", "20"  , "10" ), # unmet needs currently not included in simulation; assumed to be equal between clinics
                      prop.pts    = c(0.35, 0.35, 0.20  , 0.10)); clinics # most pts go through CT and RT, least through palliative care

prop.Control <- 0.5 # Proportion of hospitals allocated to control
Min.Pts.Treated.Per.Clinic <- 50 # No pts for full 6 month period for comparison (actually, its per hospital)
Max.Pts.Treated.Per.Clinic <- 300 # No pts for full 6 month period for comparison (actually, its per hospital)

Prpo_pts_calls_CONTROL <- 0.10
Prpo_pts_calls_INTERVENTION <-  0.20

N_simulations <- 100  #

Hosp_error_min <- -0.12
Hosp_error_max <- abs(Hosp_error_min)



# Empty dataframe to fill
results <- data.frame(N=c(), 
                      mean.pt.per.hosp=c(), 
                      pts_contr=c(), 
                      pts_exp=c(), 
                      total.var=c(),
                      Sf=c(),
                      Sl=c(),
                      Se=c(),
                      Sd=c(),
                      ICC=c(), 
                      p=c())


for(i in 1:N_simulations){
  cat("\r",  "Run =", i, "of", N_simulations)
# Data generation
  data<- data.frame(Hosp=c(1:hospitals[h]), 
                    CT=rbinom(hospitals[h],1,clinics$prop.clin.hosp[clinics$clinic== "CT"]) , 
                    RT=rbinom(hospitals[h],1,clinics$prop.clin.hosp[clinics$clinic== "RT"]) , 
                    Surg=rbinom(hospitals[h],1,clinics$prop.clin.hosp[clinics$clinic== "Surg"]) , 
                    Pal=rbinom(hospitals[h],1,clinics$prop.clin.hosp

    [clinics$clinic== "Pal"]), 
                        hosp_err= runif(hospitals[h], Hosp_error_min, Hosp_error_max))


  data$Arm <- c(rep("Control", round(hospitals[h]*prop.Control, 0)), rep("Intervention", hospitals[h] - round(hospitals[h]*prop.Control, 0))) 
  data$Pts=round(runif(hospitals[h], Min.Pts.Treated.Per.Clinic, Max.Pts.Treated.Per.Clinic), 0)
  data$CT[(data$CT+data$RT+data$Surg+data$Pal)==0] <- 1 # If no clinics assigned, assign CT
  data <- melt(data, id=c("Hosp","Arm", "Pts", "hosp_err"), variable.name="clinic")
  data <- subset(data, value==1); data <- data[-dim(data)[2]]; 
  data <- merge(data, clinics[c("clinic", "Unmet.needs", "prop.pts")], by="clinic")
  data$Pt.per.clin <- ceiling(data$Pts * data$prop.pts)

  data$simpropcalls[data$Arm == "Control"] <- Prpo_pts_calls_CONTROL
  data$simpropcalls[data$Arm == "Intervention"] <- Prpo_pts_calls_INTERVENTION
  data$simpropcalls2 <- data$simpropcalls + data$hosp_err; data$simpropcalls2[data$simpropcalls2 <0] <- 0 # Add error to introduce between hospital variation

  for(row in c(1: dim(data)[1])){data$Pts.called[row]<- rbinom(1, data$Pt.per.clin[row], data$simpropcalls2[row])}
#  for(row in c(1: dim(data)[1])){data$Pts.called2[row]<- rbinom(1, data$Pt.per.clin[row], data$simpropcalls[row])}
  data$propcalls <- round(data$Pts.called/data$Pt.per.clin , 2)

  data <- data[with(data, order(data$Hosp)), ]
  head(data, 20)

# Analysis and extraction of results
  summary(m1 <- glmer(cbind(Pts.called, Pt.per.clin-Pts.called) ~ Arm + (1|Hosp), family=binomial, data=data))

# Few lines to estimate ICC
  X <- model.matrix(m1)
  n <- nrow(X)
  Beta <- fixef(m1)
  Sf <- var(X %*% Beta) # Variance explained by fixed effect
  (Sigma.list <- VarCorr(m1))
  Sl <- as.numeric(VarCorr(m1)) # Between subject variance
  Se <- 1
  Sd <- pi^2/3
  total.var <- Sf + Sl + Se + Sd
  (ICCtemp <- Sl/total.var)

#Store results
results.temp <- data.frame(N=hospitals[h], 
                             mean.pt.per.hosp=mean(ddply(data, .(Hosp), summarize, mean.hosp.size = sum(Pt.per.clin))[[2]]),
                             pts_contr=sum(data$Pt.per.clin[data$Arm == "Control"]), 
                             pts_exp=sum(data$Pt.per.clin[data$Arm == "Intervention"]), 
                             total.var=total.var,
                             Sf=Sf,
                             Sl=Sl,
                             Se=Se,
                             Sd=Sd,
                             ICC=as.numeric(ICCtemp), 
                             p=summary(m1)$coefficients[2,4])
  results <- rbind(results, results.temp)

   } # END LOOP


# After running the code above 100s of times, 

hist(results$ICC)
results$ICC.class <- cut(results$ICC, seq(0, max(results$ICC), 0.01))
results$sign <- ifelse(results$p <0.05, 1, 0)

res <- cbind(data.frame(round(table(results$ICC.class[results$sign == 1])/table(results$ICC.class)*100, 2)),
             data.frame(table(results$ICC.class))[2]); names(res) <- c("ICC", "Power", "similations"); res # Obvisously only works with high number of simulations
# write.csv(res, paste("_Power calculation_", Prpo_pts_calls_CONTROL*100, "% vs", Prpo_pts_calls_INTERVENTION*100, "%_",hospitals[h],"hosp_hosp_err",Hosp_error_max, ".csv"))
# write.csv(results, paste("_RAW DATA_Power calculation_", Prpo_pts_calls_CONTROL*100, "% vs", Prpo_pts_calls_INTERVENTION*100, "%_",hospitals[h],"hosp_hosp_err",Hosp_error_max, ".csv"))
```

When I run 10k simulations, I get the following (unexpected) result:

(this is for 10% vs 20%, N=30 hospitals (15+15), hospital specific deviation from target proportion is -0.15 to 0.15 (sampled from uniform distribution)

```
ICC Power   simulations
(0,0.01]    NA  0
(0.01,0.02] 100 1
(0.02,0.03] 100 3
(0.03,0.04] 62.5    16
(0.04,0.05] 66.67   45
(0.05,0.06] 79.63   108
(0.06,0.07] 81.37   161
(0.07,0.08] 75.46   269
(0.08,0.09] 82.02   356
(0.09,0.1]  79.31   464
(0.1,0.11]  80.47   558
(0.11,0.12] 82.58   706
(0.12,0.13] 82.13   705
(0.13,0.14] 83.44   779
(0.14,0.15] 83.25   794
(0.15,0.16] 85.37   752
(0.16,0.17] 85.79   760
(0.17,0.18] 88.64   678
(0.18,0.19] 92.78   609
(0.19,0.2]  88.81   536
(0.2,0.21]  88.31   402
(0.21,0.22] 87.98   341
(0.22,0.23] 92.94   255
(0.23,0.24] 93.07   202
(0.24,0.25] 86.96   138
(0.25,0.26] 92.44   119
(0.26,0.27] 87.36   87
(0.27,0.28] 96.77   62
(0.28,0.29] 97.78   45
(0.29,0.3]  90  20
(0.3,0.31]  100 9
(0.31,0.32] 100 6
(0.32,0.33] 88.89   9
(0.33,0.34] 100 1
```

The ‘power’ would only be valid over the range for which many simulations were run obviously. For example, we see that for an ICC of around 0.15, we would have about 83-85% power to detect a difference between control/experimental hospitals when using 30 hospitals in total (15 contr +15 exp). One thing that is clear, is that the power does NOT decrease with increasing ICC, which we would expect. So something is wrong in the coding… 
Would it have to do with the way ICC  is calculated? An increase in ICC is either an increase in between hospital variance, a decrease in within hospital variance, or both.

Not sure how to proceed…
Comments welcome!

EDIT 1: I guess its not really fair to look at the power within the *observed* ICC. I should be looking at the power under the *true ICC*. I guess then my biggest problem is how to simulate data sets with with a fixed underlying ICC...

Comment: yikes, this is a lot to digest.  It may be hard to get people to spend long enough to absorb the whole thing.  I certainly haven't yet.  You might take a look at `?simulate.merMod`, which has a simulate-from-scratch capability (nothing you haven't already implemented yourself, but maybe a different code path would have different bugs)